# Woocommerce Currency switcher converts the shipping rate twice?

Tags: woocommerce

In WooCommerce Currency Switcher v.1.1.4, while checking the shipping rates by of products when I switch over from USD to CAD, 5$(USD) converts to 9.44(CAD).

It converts my shipping rates twice. Please help me to fix this issue.